# Espaçamento entre Background

Tags: html, css, css3

Boa tarde. Gostaria de saber se é possível dar um espaçamento entre o 'Background-repeat'. Ou seja, estou com algo assim:

[Imagem com exemplo](http://ap.imagensbrasil.org/image/0LQkmj)

Meu CSS está assim:

```
background-image: url(imagens/half-circle-brown.png), url(imagens/half-circle-white.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-size:12px;
background-position:0% 100%, 0% 0%;
height: 100%;
```

Gostaria de saber se há como colocar um espaçamento entre cada background-repeate, ou seja, em cada circulo, tanto no marrom quanto no branco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie a imagem com fundo transparente (png ou gif transparente) acresentando o espaçamento na imagem conforme exemplo a seguir para a imagem half-circle-brown.png.

[image: semi-círculo inferior]